# How do I get an RPM .spec file from FPM (Effing Package Management)?

Tags: package-management, centos-6, rpmbuild

I have made a package with Effing Package Management on CentOS 6, and sent people the `fpm`... stuff to generate it. It looks like some of these people I trust would like to see a .spec file, too.

I searched through [FPM's GitHub](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=.spec+file) and the most recent advice I found about doing this was at [this link](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/issues/689) (RPM: support for just generating the RPM spec file #689). Good advice, but it ended up not really doing the trick.

Also, as far as I know, [.rpm files don't usually contain a .spec file so nice and neat, normally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613954/extract-the-spec-file-from-rpm-package).

How do I get `fpm` to spit me out a good old .spec file if I need one?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage FPM's ability to edit SPEC files (-e) to get it to dump the generated one to a file by setting the FPM_EDITOR env variable:

```
FPM_EDITOR="cat >spec_file " fpm -e -s dir -t rpm -n test test_dir
```

Comment: // , Isn't that just a dummy spec file, though? It looks like it's just a bunch of noops.